# WS-Discovery Proxy (Ubuntu, gSOAP, C++)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, web-services, gsoap, ws-discovery

WS-Discovery Proxy

I've been trying to get an older example of a WS-Discovery Proxy implemented in C++ to run. It can be found here https://github.com/mpromonet/ws-discovery
I know it's a shot in the dark, but I really need a working Discovery Proxy, and this seems to be the closest thing to it. I am not sure whether the package is simply too old to run nowadays, or whether I am missing something, but if there's a way to get it to run, that'd be great.

After fighting through countless errors and dependencies on Ubuntu, I've managed to make some progress, but I got stuck.

I've tried to get it to work with the following versions of gSOAP:
The latest version from soruceforge - /projects/gsoap2/
https://github.com/stoneyrh/gSOAP
https://github.com/alisw/gsoap/tree/master

Although the outcome with different versions of gSOAP is quite different, I end up looking at a blank wall, and in the end it doesn't run.

With the older version of gSOAP (the last link), I get an version missmatch error.
[Old gSOAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coTMu.png)
[image]

With the newer one (latest version from SF), I get the following:
[New gSOAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NH49.png)
[image]

If I didn't describe my problem well enough, I'd be happy to address it, let me know if you need any additional info. I'm new to all this, so I might be missing something fundamental here. If that's the case, please do point it out to me. I'd be happy to try something new and learn by doing it. In case you have a working example of the Discovery Proxy (Python, C, C++ or anything else), and you'd be kind enough to share it with me, it would help me out a ton.